# Is it possible to view all answers via rss?

Tags: support, feed

Is there a RSS feed for a given question?

I want to download all the answers for a given question (all be sure to follow the rules of the license etc.)

Is this possible or do you need the entire database to do this or manually pull them out somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/199247) is the feed for this question.  The link is:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/199247

There is a link called "question feed" in the bottom right hand corner of the page:

> [image]

Comment: that's funny, some questions dont have that feed and even replacing the question id doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Blankman Do you have some examples?  I just looked at a handful and they all had it.  Were you on a beta site by chance?

Comment: nope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered

Comment: @Blankman That question is locked, and as such new answers cannot be posted to it.